# flyway migration on existing database results in "wrong column type encountered in column"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, migration, flyway

i have spring boot application that uses my database schema. Lets say i have non-empty schema with table `APPLICATION_USERS` defined as follows:

```
create table AREA
(
  name NVARCHAR2(36) not null,
  id   NUMBER not null
)
```

now i wanted to add FlyWay to my application. I have defined in my application properties `flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true` to start initial Flyway deployment and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` to validate my Enities agains schema,  however upon starting application i get following error:

```
 wrong column type encountered in column [name] in table [APPLICATION_USERS]; found [nvarchar2 (Types#OTHER)], but expecting [varchar2(255 char) (Types#VARCHAR)]
```

as far as i understand it, it complains about `NVARCHAR2`, as it expect `varchar` how can i force hibernate to accept `nvarchar2` as `varchar`?

i know i can use `columnDefinition` on my entity attributes, however this is not my dream solution, is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are using Oracle database.

You have to annotate your the attribute name in your Entity with Nationalized

```
@Nationalized
private String name;
```

You also could register your own dialect:

```
public class CustomOracleDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {

    public CustomOracleDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.NVARCHAR, "nvarchar2($l)");
        registerHibernateType(Types.NVARCHAR, StandardBasicTypes.STRING.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: you are ofcoure correct, however i have hundreds of such cases throughout my entire application, so adding this annotation would be really painfull, is there some other way?

Comment: Yes you could register your own Dialect. I will add this to my answer